# Title of a book about living aboard a ship being consumed by fungus?

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a story about 25 to 30 years ago regarding being trapped on a sailing ship alone and slowly noticing a fungus that creeps over everything, eventually consuming the narrator.

The story is not "The Voice in the Night" by William Hope Hodgson, but very similar in theme.

The differences are that the narrator of the story I'm looking for is alone, there is no fungus island, and the story is novel-length, not a short story.