# Possibly a 80s horror comic question

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror

I remember a particular story in a comic in the UK (could have been a US import though), it regards a couple on a honeymoon cruise on a liner.

The ship picks up someone in a lifeboat (or directly from the sea?), but it turns out that this person has some sort of disease that turns the victim into an overgrown monster (bit hulk-like).

The disease is passed on by touch, and spreads through the ship like wildfire. The newly-weds are soon the only ones left, and as they prepare to jump overboard, the wife gets infected and the husband must escape alone.

Any ideas? Bit vague I know!
Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Perhaps "The Fog" if it was filmatised?

Answer (score 2):

It may be a graphic adaptation of a short story ['The Voice in the Night'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voice_in_the_Night) by William Hope Hodgson.

Apparently adapted by many other writers in different formats.

Comment: Then again, maybe it's an adaptation of [this unidentified story](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39425/title-of-a-book-about-living-aboard-a-ship-being-consumed-by-fungus).